# HTTP POST x-protobuf data using axios

Tags: typescript, rest, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js

Previously I used `request` lib to send my requests, but since it is deprecated I'm moving to axios.

It looked like this:

```
const request = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    encoding: null,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/x-protobuf',
    },
    body: requestEncoder.encode(data).finish(),
  };

  const {body} = await http.request(request);
  const results: any[] = [];
  const reader = protobuf.Reader.create(body as unknown as Uint8Array);
  while (reader.pos < reader.len) {
    results.push(responseEncoder.decodeDelimited(reader));
  }
  return results;
```

now in using axios I am doing the following:

```
  const response = await axios.post(
    url,
    requestEncoder.encode(data).finish(),
    {headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-protobuf'}, responseType: 'arraybuffer'});

  const results: any[] = [];
  const reader = protobuf.Reader.create( new Uint8Array(response.data) as unknown as Uint8Array);
  while (reader.pos < reader.len) {
    results.push(responseEncoder.decodeDelimited(reader));
  }
  return results;
```

However I get error:

```
 RangeError: index out of range: 98 + 101 > 149
```

Could anyone help figure out what I am doing wrong as it worked previously?